# Making an Android container with Ubuntu 12.04 on the Samsung ARM Chromebook : initrd file not found

Tags: ubuntu, android, arm, lxc, chrome-book

I'm trying to run Android as guest OS with LXC containers on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on the ARM Chromebook, reading [this tutorial](https://www.stgraber.org/2013/12/23/lxc-1-0-some-more-advanced-container-usage/#comment-181820).

At some point of the tutorial, it says:

> Then get the `initrd` for your device and place it in `/var/lib/lxc/android/initrd.gz`

What does that mean? Do I have to rename `initrd` to `initrd.gz`? Where can I get the `initrd` file? It is not inside the Android container. Between the Android files I can see only these:

```
init
init.goldfish.rc
init.mahimahi.rc
init.rc
```

Comment: initrd is usually store inside /boot